# Copy-Constructor is not working

Tags: c++

I wrote a C++ program where a Copy Constructor is part of. The program is working with a matrix, and I use a copy constructor to create a new matrix (that is like the first one of course).

When I work with a source matrix like 3 3 it works fine, but when I work with a (for example) 3 2 matrix, the copy constructor is not working. The problem is odd and please try it for yourself, here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class Matrix {

private:
    //Zeiger auf den Array, der die Matrix darstellt.
    double* m;
    //Zeilenanzahl
    size_t rows;
    //Spaltenanzahl
    size_t cols;

public:
    Matrix(size_t r, size_t c) {
        m = new double[r * c];
        rows = r;
        cols = c;

        cout << "Konstruktor für " << this << endl;
    }

    //Copy-Konstruktor
    Matrix(const Matrix &obj) {

        cout << "Copy-Constructor" << endl;

        rows = obj.rows;
        cols = obj.cols;
        m = new double[rows*cols];

        //neuen Array m mit Werten füllen
        for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
            for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; ++col) {
                m[row * rows + col] = obj.get(row, col);
            }
        }
    }

    size_t numRows() const {
        return rows;
    }

    size_t numCols() const {
        return cols;
    }

    void set(int row, int col, double value) {
        m[row * rows + col] = value;
    }

    int get(int row, int col) const {
        return m[row * rows + col];
    }

    ~Matrix() {
        cout << "Destruktor für " << this << endl;
        delete[] m;
        m = 0;
    }

};

//Matrix wird in die Konsole geschrieben
void print(const Matrix &m) {

    for (size_t row = 0; row < m.numRows(); ++row) {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < m.numCols(); ++col) {

            cout << m.get(row, col) << "\t";

        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    cout << "Programmstart" << endl;

    if (argc < 3) {
        cout << "Brauche Anzahlen von Zeilen und Spalten für Matrizen!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int rows = atoi(argv[1]);
    int cols = atoi(argv[2]);

    Matrix m1(rows, cols);

    for (size_t row = 0; row < m1.numRows(); ++row) {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < m1.numCols(); ++col) {
            double value = row + col;
            // Mit Matrix::set() soll dem Element in der angegebenen Zeile und
            // Spalte ein Wert zugewiesen werden können.
            m1.set(row, col, value);
        }
    }
    cout << "m1 Element (0, 0) ist: " << m1.get(0, 0) << endl;

    cout << "m1:" << endl;
    print(m1);

    Matrix m2(m1);
    cout << "m2:" << endl;
    print(m2);

    cout << "Programmende" << endl;
}
```

I hope someone sees the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't all of the `m[row * rows + col]` expressions actually be `m[row * cols + col]`? In the copy constructor *and* in your `get` and `set` methods?

Comment: Did you enable all warnings & debug info when compiling (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`)? Did you **use the debugger** (`gdb`) ?

Comment: "The copy constructor is not working" ...... you must describe and explain your problem if you want help fixing it.

Comment: @Basile: I compiled with : g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic Test.cpp - no Warnings where given

Comment: @Lightness: The program breaks and a dialog pops up with: "The programm is not working anymore" (my translation).

Comment: But did you use the debugger?

Comment: Just did a quick debug. It gives a warning : [New Thread 2784.0xa88]
warning: HEAP[Test.exe]: 
warning: Heap block at 00762508 modified at 00762540 past requested size of 30

Comment: I wrote over some Array-limits ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m[row * rows + col] = obj.get(row, col);` should be

```
m[row * cols + col] = obj.get(row, col);
```

Also revise you `get` method to:

```
int get(int row, int col) const {
   return m[row * cols + col];
}
```